# Tcl array get does not work with :: in proc

Tags: arrays, tcl, global, environment

See the Tcl code below:

```
proc foo {} {
    puts "env get is:[array get ::env "DODA" ]"
}
set env("DODA") bar
foo
exit
```

I would expect that the output would be
`env get is:{DODA bar}`
Instead, it returns just empty list for the array get, namely:
`env get is:`
Any ideas what am I doing wrong? This is Tcl 8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Tcl`, the arrays are associative arrays. With that, the double quotes and braces behave as separate entity when it comes to array's index.

```
% set user(name) dinesh
dinesh
% set user("name") DINESH
DINESH
% set user({name}) Dinesh
Dinesh
% parray user
user("name") = DINESH
user(name)   = dinesh
user({name}) = Dinesh
% array size user
3
```

As you can see, the entries `name`, `"name"`, `{name}` are different.

Now, in your case, you have created the index `"DODA"` with double quotes.

```
% set env("DODA") bar
bar
% puts "env get is:[array get ::env \"DODA\" ]"
env get is:{"DODA"} bar
%
```

Or otherwise,

```
% set env(DODA) bar
bar
% puts "env get is:[array get ::env DODA ]"
env get is:DODA bar
%
```

Comment: Well, that sorts it out... Cheers.